# How to deal with json data put it into FlatList with numColumns={2}?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have asked the similar question, but i find that my real problem is how to deal with my jsondata and return it.

In my case, i can't figure it out how to map the data and return it with only one `<View>`.  In my function `renderRow`, it looks like i return two `<View>` cause i can't set `numColumns={2}` in `FlatList`. It will show error `Element type is invalid`

Any one can save me from the world. I stuck over here.

Here is my `App.js` i fetch an API to get the jsondata:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.state = { movies: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=ThisWeek')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
        this.setState({ movies: responseData });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  renderRow(movies) {
    console.log('renderRow => ');
    console.log(movies)
    return movies.item.movie.map(movie => 
      <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: movie.photoHref}} style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const movies = this.state.movies;
    console.log('render');
    console.log(movies);
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={movies}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          numColumns={2}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my debug console:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your response data properly, I have made a couple of changes and was able to see 2 images per row, here are the changes

**changed how you are setting movies to state**

```
this.setState({ movies: responseData[0].movie });
```

You need to put precaution before accessing **responseData[0]**, I just access it to see the result

**Changed renderRow as follows**

```
renderRow({item: movie}) {
    return (
       <View>
           <Image source={{ uri: movie.photoHref}} style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }} />
       </View>
    );
}
```

Rest it just same.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you @Prasun. I don't even think i can set my jsondata like this . You help me a lot . Thank your very much.

Comment: You are welcome, but be careful while accessing the responseData, do check the array before accessing. If responseData do not have the array, your APP will crash.